# Problema pasando información entre querys en nodejs/expressjs

Tags: mysql, nodejs, reactjs, express, axios

A ver, tengo 2 bases de datos, y quiero guardar en variables la información que obtengo de una primera consulta a la base de datos y usarla para insertarla en la otra. Lo estoy planteando de la siguiente manera:
(el frontEnd lo estoy trabajando con React y el backend con NodeJS y expressJS)

1. Realizo una consulta SQL que me devuelve el id, nombre y apellidos de un usuario desde la base de datos.
2. Guardo la información que quiero en estas 3 variables.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. Intento hacer otra consulta pero esta vez insertando la informacion que me he guardado  junto a la que recibo de otro formulario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, en la respuesta que se me devuelve por consola, los valores de id, nombre y usuario estan a NULL

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código completo lo paso por aquí ->  https://pastebin.com/HAe54zbE

Comment: El código y los mensajes de error deben ir _en la pregunta_, _como texto, con formato_. Pon además en el título el problema que estás teniendo. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

una forma de trabajar este tipo operaciones en NodeJs con el login sería la siguiente. Sin embargo para que funcione tiene que decirle a node que acepte transacciones tipo json

```
//para que eso funcione tiene que decirle que va a realizar transacciones en json
app.use(express.json());
```

De lo contrario no funcionará. Bueno sin más preambulos:

```
//personalmente cambiaría el nombre de la ruta porque es más diciente, 
//cuando se crece el proyecto es bueno saber a que se refiera cada cosa
//así los nombres sean largos
app.post('/loginVacaciones', (req, res) => {

  //Valido que me envién algo como parámetro en el body
  //porque si no mas abajo da error
  let { user, pass } = req.body
  if (!user || !pass) {
    return res.json({
      msg: !user && !pass
        ? 'El usuario y la contraseña son requeridos'
        : !user
          ? 'Usuario requerido'
          : 'Contraseña requerida'
    })
  }
  //me gusta primero consultar si existe el usuario 
  db.query('SELECT * FROM usu WHERE usu_id = ?', [user], (err, result) => {
    //después valido e imprimo en consola la respuesta 
    console.log(result.length > 0
      ? pass === result[0].usu_key
        ? result[0]
        : 'Contraseña Incorrecta'
      : 'Usuario No existe')

    //devuelvo la respuesto al usuario
    //que si todo está bien me retornará el usuario
    // let { msg, user } = data; // así se reciben los datos en el cliente
    return res.json(result.length > 0
      ? pass === result[0].usu_key
        ? { user: result[0] }
        : { msg: 'Contraseña Incorrecta' }
      : { msg: 'Usuario No existe' })
  });
});
```

bueno yo vi eso como un login, aunque pensandolo bien ya no. bueno igual aplica si solo es consultar. También la forma de insertar datos no me convence, hay opciones mas cencillas si las aprendes a usar, personalmente me gusta esta.

```
app.post('/createVacaciones', (req, res) => {

  //el cuerpo viene en json
  /*  
  {
     id_empleado: 111,
     nombre: 'Anton',
     apellido: 'Gamboa',
     fechaInicio: 'hoy',
     fechaFinal: 'Mañana'
  }
    */
  let { cuerpo } = req.body;

  db.query(
    "INSERT INTO vacaciones set ?",
    [cuerpo],
    (err, result) => {
      console.log(
        err
          ? "err create " + err
          : 'vacaciones added!'
      );
      res.json(err ? { err: 'err create' } : { msg: 'vacaciones added!' });
    }
  );
});
```

Si notas se vuelve el código más limpio y le puedes enviar un objeto del tamaño que tú quieras en formato json. Un plus, esta es una forma de llamar desde visual studio con la extensión REST Client

```
POST http://localhost:5000/server/createVacaciones HTTP/1.1
Content - Type: application / json

 {
  'id_empleado': 111,
  'nombre': 'Anton',
  'apellido': 'Gamboa',
  'fechaInicio': 'hoy',
  'fechaFinal': 'Mañana'
  }
```

Claro también puede probarlo desde postman. Bueno un gran saludo, espero que aunque es un poco larga la respuesta se entienda y sea clara para que muchos puedan usarla. Quedo atento